# Select option with max value?

Tags: html

I want to set the select option as how the input is.

In input tag we can do this:

```
  <input type="number" max="100" min="0"/>
```

And now I want to do this in select option:

```
  <select>
      <option max="100" value="100">100</option>
      <option max="200" value="200">200</option>
  <select>
```

The reason is I just want to ensure if the value which is selected by user is appropriate as real value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are asking, but I'm going to assume you are asking whether there are alternatives to using `select`.

If you are looking to allow users to select a range of numbers (eg. 100-200), you can choose to use a Html Slider Bar. There are plenty of simple tutorials out there that teaches you how to use a slider bar.

An example of a [HTML5 Slider Bar Tutorial](http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/).

Otherwise, if you want a fixed value (eg. 100 OR 200), a `select` option will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to check is the selected option correct in case when not every options in the template are corrects.
You have to use CustomValidity, like this:

```
<select id="select">
   <option value="100">100</option>
   <option value="200">200</option>
<select>
```

But, because of some reason now the  only 100 is valid

```
let select = document.querySelector('#select');

let setSelectValidity = function () {
      if (select.value !== 100) {
          select.setCustomValidity('The only 100 is available');
      else {
          select.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}

select.addEventListener('change', setSelectValidity);
```